# What are symbolic solutions to this system? Computer aided solutions are fine

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

What are the symbolic solutions to this? I've only gotten approximations so far. I'm not very interested in how to solve it, I'm more interested in the solutions.

$$eb-dg-e(-e-b+e^2)+g=0$$
$$-dge+d+b(-e-b+e^2)-eg+1=b$$
$$ed+bg-e-dg(-e-b-e^2)=0$$
$$b-dg^2+d(-e-b+e^2)=-dg$$
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry!

Comment: Explain the weird use of +-.

Comment: I just didn't bother to get rid of them a+-b=a-b. I'll get rid of them now

Comment: Nope, including complex numbers

Comment: As far as I see, $d=-1$ and all the rest equal to zeros should work?